# Property value not showing in SoapUI Response

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I'm relatively new to groovy and soapUI, but I am trying to use a test suite to check some requests/responses. I have three testCases. Two of them are dependent on a value I set in the third. My problem is, I can't reference the value in the third case in either of the first two. The first two tests basically run the same request, one fills the entire form with data and the other only fills only the required parts and the clientTID is one of the required parts (but I didn't get any data to put in there, so I made a value called "TransID" to do it). So the entire testSuite fails because of the value from the third test case. I wrote this:

**TestCase1/TestCase2**, Test Requests:

```
<clientOrderRequest>
    <clientTID>${TransID}</clientTID>
    <transactionCount>5</transactionCount>
    <ClientInformation> unimportant information here </ClientInformation></clientOrderRequest>
```

**TestCase3**, Groovy Script:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("TransID", String.valueOf((int)Math.random()*1000000000))
```

When it's run, I get:

**TestCase1/TestCase2**, Test Requests raw:

```
<clientOrderRequest>
    <clientTID></clientTID>
    <transactionCount>5</transactionCount>
    <ClientInformation> Unimportant information here </ClientInformation></clientOrderRequest>
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic here, but... how can I get the field in clientID to show up? I've tried a [bunch of different things](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html) but I haven't gotten the transID value to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

One (if I make this numeric, SO screws up the formatting?): Run your TestCase3 first, and set the property at Project level.

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("TransID", '(int)Math.random()*1000000000'.toString())
```

If this is the only thing that this test case does, then you can even put the above code in the test suite SetUp script (with appropriate edits). In your subsequent test cases you would then refer to this as `${#Project#TransID}`

Two: In your two test cases you could use *Groovy* property expansion. It would look something like:

```
${=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName('TestCase3').getPropertyValue('TransID')}
```

Comment: @Ice-9 If you like the answer, can you accept it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: The first one is a Project level property, not global.

Answer (score 1):

`${TransID}` would be referencing a global property named TransID. You need to reference a testCase property. Try changing it to the following:

```
<clientOrderRequest>
    <clientTID>${#TestCase#TransID}</clientTID>
    <transactionCount>5</transactionCount>
    <ClientInformation> unimportant information here </ClientInformation>
</clientOrderRequest>
```

If that doesn't work. Try using global properties. Simply do the following.

1. In Preferences create a global property called TransID
2. Change `testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("TransID", String.valueOf((int)Math.random()*1000000000))` 
   to `SoapUI.getGlobalProperties().getProperty('TransID').setValue(String.valueOf((int)Math.random()*1000000000))`
3. Leave your `${TransID}` reference as is in both your testCase's

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't seem to work. I think #TestCase# looks in the containing testCase for the variable, so it wouldn't see the TransID value.

Comment: Wait, you have a seperate testCase that is running the groovy script teststep? You cant reference a testCase property thats in a different testCase. Have you thought of having the groovy test step (or even run it as a setup script) in testCase1 and testCase2?

Comment: I can't. The tests run parallel and testcase1 and 2 need the same value in the clientTID field for the test to run correctly. So if I put the TransID value in either Test1 or Test2, one of them would still need to reference a property outside of itself.

Comment: I added a secondary option to my answer which should work in your situation as it uses Global Properties.